# Python: Having trouble understanding regex

Tags: python, regex, django

I was going through the django tutorial and though now almost everything there seems pretty  clear, I am having trouble understanding the regex while matching the urls :

`r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$`

what does `(?P<poll_id>\d+)` do ?

I am understanding that after stripping off the `"34/"` from `"polls/34/"`, The `polls.url` is being called and there the keyword `urlpatterns` is being looked for , but how does `poll_id` get this value `34` ?

I know only a bit of regex, so thats why it might be hard for me to read. 
Also, here is the reference that I am using for this question :[Tutorial Part3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a regex that takes the `poll_id` (a number) as a variable.

The corresponding view is:

```
def detail(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at poll %s." % poll_id)
```

Now when you go to `example.com/polls/34/`, it knows you are looking for `poll` number `34`, and it brings that in to the view as the `poll_id`.

So in your view, `poll_id = 34`. This allows you to display or manipulate this specific poll.

Essentially the point of the regex in this case is to allow you to view a large number of specific polls without having to create an explicit url for each one.

To clarify, this regex is saying take any number `\d+`, save it as `poll_id`, and proceed to this view with that `poll_id`.

Comment: SO is this a standard way to write the regex `?P<variable_name>` ?

Comment: While `?P<variable_name>` is part of the regex, that is the part that saves the variable. The actual regex search in this case is `\d+`. So essentially regex is saying take any number - `\d+`, save it as `variable_name`, and take that `variable_name` to this view.

Comment: Brilliant, got my answer :D

Answer (score 2):

To support for Dan Hoerst 's answer: yup, django uses regular expression to extract the poll_id for the view. The underneath of this is:

```
import re 
r = re.compile(r'^poll/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$')
r.match('poll/132/').groups() # ('132',)
```